# Obj-c dot notation for reading properties: why can't i combine it like this?

Tags: objective-c, properties

i have this line of code:

```
[[[EntitlementsManager instance] entitlements] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Why won't it work in the way below:

```
[EntitlementsManager.instance.entitlements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Seems like it should work to me? I'm a little confused as to why it doesn't compile.

FYI, EntitlementsManager, 'instance' is the '+' method to return its singleton, and 'entitlements' is an NSArray property.

-edit: For those why say it doesn't work because 'instance' is a static '+' method, then why does the following work just fine? I'm really intrigued:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return EntitlementsManager.instance.entitlements.count;
}
```

-edit2: This *does* work, strangely:

```
... = [[EntitlementsManager instance].entitlements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: dot notation is syntactical sugar.

Comment: What’s the actual error given by the compiler? What’s the declaration of EntitlementsManager?

Comment: Actual error is 'expected identifier'.

Comment: Yeah, I’ve reproduced your error on both GCC and Clang/LLVM. Not sure why it happens, though.

Comment: Yeah, it really should work, but the compilers don't behave properly in this case. Note, that the following does work: `blahblah = EntitlementsManager.instance.entitlements;`, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the parser got confused when it sees a *Type* appearing on the left of a `.` inside an Obj-C method call. For example, if the grammar

```
'[' Type   methodAndArguments ']'
```

exists, then it will be parsed before recognizing `a '.' b`, and since `.instance ...` isn't an expected construct of *methodAndArguments*, the compiler will fail. As `Type.method` isn't one expected use of the dot syntax, it is valid for the compiler *not* to support it, or even making its use a syntax error in the future.

Either always use the bracket notation for class methods as you're expected to:

```
[[EntitlementsManager instance].entitlements objectAtIndex:0]
```

or move that expression outside of bracket:

```
NSArray* entitlements = EntitlementsManager.instance.entitlements;
[entitlements objectAtIndex:0];
```

or force that `'[' Type methodAndArguments ']'` not to be matched:

```
[(nil, EntitlementsManager.instance.entitlements) objectAtIndex:0]
```

Comment: Wow, sounds complicated. I'll just rack it up to a compiler bug/oddity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

[(EntitlementsManager.instance.entitlements) objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

might work

Comment: Doesn't work, i get 'expected )' even though it certainly is there.